# There's a way to pass a variable from userdata to docker-compose to nginx in a EC2 instance

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am trying to mount a nginx server with docker compose in an instance of EC2 I need to pass an environment variable, that varibale is defined in the user data of the instance

I tryed to uploaded it with the environment option of the docker compose but when the nginx is uploaded it creates a static code and can't be replaced making reference with "process.env.KEY", I want to know if there's a way to pass the variable to nginx maybe before the build, or update the static files after they have been created

> userdata.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo KEY=keyexpected >> /etc/environment
```

> docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  container1:
                container_name: container1
                image: image1
                restart: always
                network_mode: bridge
                environment:
                        - KEY=${KEY}
                ports:
                - 8080:80
  container2:
                container_name: container2
                image: image2
                restart: always
                network_mode: bridge
                ports:
                - 3000:3000
```

> Javascript file that will be build by ngnix

```
const path = { key: process.env.KEY };
console.log(path.key)
```

> Dockerfile of Node project

```
FROM nginx:1.15.2-alpine

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/

COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

COPY build /usr/share/nginx/html/

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

expected: 
console.log(path.key) ----> "keyexpected"

actual: 
process.env.KEY is undefined

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
#!/bin/bash
echo KEY="keyexpected" >> /etc/profile
```

Comment: Didn't work, the problem is that "process.env.KEY" is already builded with nginx and is static code, the variable should be added when you build the nginx but at this time you don't know its value yet